# Program to view what a webpage would look through a mobile phone

Tags: iphone

I know this might off subject but what's a good program let's me view what a website might look like on a iPhone or other mobile device which connects to the Internet. Dreamweaver cs3 might have this but I can't find it anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Use the iphone simulator (part of the iphone SDK) and go to the webpage you want to test using safari.

Very simple except you will need a intel mac ( can be done on a ppc mac but installing the SDK requires some tricks on ppc and is not supported).

Comment: How about a of? Know of any software?

Comment: I don't know of any tool for a pc, sorry

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) has an [iPhone plug-in](http://www.aptana.com/iphone) which also includes a built in display. All of which are free.

Answer (score 1):

Iphone Similutor is one which i use and its work perfectally fine and its avlaible with iphone SDK